# Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver for xHtml Web Pages?

Tags: selenium

I want to select a portion of text in a WebPage. When I check for the xPath for the portion of text. I found this is a xHtml page. So Can we use the Selenium WebDriver for this.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/U6A5FktzLMQ it is only partially supported. The problem is with the namespaces that you can define in the xhtml. it's a good discussion thought it might be outdated.